# Is this sentence wrong? Must an action verb like 買いました always use を？

Tags: grammar

父は姉のセーター**が**デパートで買いました。

Is this sentence wrong due to the が?　Must an action verb like 買いました always use を？

I don't remember where I read it, but it said that in many cases, using が will not be wrong since it marks a statement. While if the verb require が (such as すき or 欲しい）it will be wrong to use を.

Comment: What would that sentence mean if it were correct? I am a native speaker and I have no idea what it means.  My brain just won't take it.

Comment: 父がデパートで姉のセーターを買いました。

Comment: Perhaps what you read about was [は replacing を](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14708/5010)?

Comment: Also, it might help to understand that 買う is a verb while both 欲しい and 好き are adjectives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. セーター in your example sentence is a object, so you must use を because を is usually used for a object.

As for すき and 欲しい, you are right.