# why is は used rather than を here?

Tags: particles

i had listened to true love restraint and there's this line here

> 今誰を見てるの？ 僕以外は見ないで

why is it は and not を「僕以外を見ないで」 even when を was explicitly used in the first line with the same idea? what's the difference? and if は is here to convey something different than を how does it change the meaning from just using を instead anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14791/9831 「酒**を**飲みますか？」「酒**は**飲みません。」/「北極にはシロクマなど陸上の動物**が**いる。南極には陸上の動物**は**いない。」/ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/9831 "Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements" See "The contrast marker and negation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

は is often used in place of をto add emphasis to that specific object, in this case 僕 (no other than JUST me).