# How is ではなく formed?

Tags: syntax, particle-は, negation, copula, renyōkei

> この女の人はペンチ**ではなく**、ハンマーを使っています。

I believe the sentence means

> The woman is using a hammer, not a pliers.

But I couldn't understand ではなく, how is this structure formed?

Comment: In linguistics, this is sometimes called "metalinguistic negation".  "Metalinguistic comparison" is a related concept: 先生**というより**学者だ ("[He] is more a scholar than a teacher.")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- で: The continuative form of the copula だ.
- は: The topic/contrast marker は, [which is optional](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8280/5010) but [is usually placed here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010). では can be contracted to じゃ in casual settings.
- なく: The continuative form of ない.
- (て): なく can be followed by an optional て. In casual conversation て tends to be used, and in formal essays て tends to be dropped.

Put together this literally means "not being ～". Practically this can be used wherever a noun can be used in a sentence, and means "not ～ (but ～)". This can be used with adverbs, too.

> - 彼ではなく私がやりました。　＝　彼じゃなくて私がやりました。
> - 彼は壁を赤くではなく青く塗った。
> - ゆっくりではなく、急いで来てください。